# what's the backbone way to update the url hash to a user click

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a little backbone gallery that will have 3 images.

This will be the 'default page'

```
http://localhost:3000/arc/location2/8
```

the subsequent states will be:

```
http://localhost:3000/arc/location2/8#image/1
http://localhost:3000/arc/location2/8#image/2
```

What is the standard way for updating this hashchange to get to #image/1 or #image/2? I obviously don't want it to be a href (or do I) since this will reload the page.

not?

```
<a href='#image/1'>next</a>
```

Is the model to just write a little jQuery helper method to catch clicks and then set window.location.hash?

Comment: Most everything that you're looking for in covered [right here](http://backbonejs.org/#Router).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {

    // Matches #page/10, passing "10"
    this.route("page/:number", "page", function(number){ 
      // some code manipulating your page
    });

   }
});
```

To trigger a route change you would just call "navigate".

```
Router.navigate("page/" + pageNumber);
```

You may also need to do some research into pushState. This gives the browser the ability to utiilize the back/forward buttons to move between Backbone routes. [More info here](http://backbonejs.org/#History).

Comment: thx Mike, so are you saying I should capture in like a jQuery event and increment / decrement via Router.navigate. For, the right / left arrow key, I implemented with something like                 `window.location.hash="image/" + prev;` - would this be equivalent?

Comment: If I were you I would check out [http://backbonejs.org/#History](http://backbonejs.org/#History).

Comment: thx Mike, I might not be understanding exactly what you're saying but where would I trigger